# Collection View cell in Table View Controller (like Tinder Message tab)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collectionview, tinder

it is my first time to use Stack Overflow:) hope I can find the answers and give my knowledges.

I am currently making a chat app like Tinder or instagram style for studying Swift.

as you can see on Tinder, you can swipe horizontally matched users

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFUcM.jpg

I want to build almost same design like that.

on my main.storyboard, it is like

```
TableViewController

   -collectionView

        -collectionViewCell
        -collectionViewFlowLayout

   -tableViewCell

        -contentView
```

like this.

collectionView cell is for matched users, 
and tableviewCells are for opened chatrooms.

I already finished making chatrooms.

but the collection view part never shows up. 
I tried to make Extension.swift file for this and typed like

```
 extension TableViewController {


   class RequestCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var MatchedAvatar: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var MatchedName: UILabel!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
   MatchedAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = 30
   MatchedAvatar.clipsToBounds = true

    }


    let horizontalView = UIView(backgroundColor: .blue)

          }
 }
```

I thought about build a storyboard like

```
ViewController

   -collectionView

        -collectionViewCell
        -collectionViewFlowLayout

   -tableView

        -contentView
```

I really have no idea why it is not working. :( is there any way I can make like tinder?

thanks for reading and sorry for my English, lack of explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample project for you on github
https://github.com/manojaher88/CollectionViewInTableView

below is the code that might help you

```
// MARK:- CellType
enum CellType: Int, CaseIterable {
    case newMatches = 0
    case messages
}

// MARK:- NewMatch
struct NewMatch {
    let name: String
    let imageName: String
}

// MARK:- ViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   enum Constants {
    static let nibName = "CollectionTableViewCell"
    static let reuseIdentifier = "CollectionTableViewCell"
}

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

private var newMatches: [NewMatch] = []
private var newMessages: [NewMatch] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupTableView()
    createDataSource()
}

private func setupTableView() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    let nibName = UINib(nibName: Constants.nibName, bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: Constants.reuseIdentifier)
}

private func createDataSource() {
    for i in 0...3 {
        let newMatch = NewMatch(name: "Matches \(i)", imageName: "image_1")
        newMatches.append(newMatch)
    }

    for i in 0...3 {
        let newMatch = NewMatch(name: "Messages \(i)", imageName: "image_1")
        newMessages.append(newMatch)
    }
}
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return CellType.allCases.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CollectionTableViewCell else {
        fatalError()
    }
    var dataSource: [NewMatch] = []
    let cellType = CellType(rawValue: indexPath.section)
    switch cellType {
    case .newMatches:   dataSource = newMatches
    case .messages:     dataSource = newMessages
    case .none: break
    }
    cell.update(newModels: dataSource)

    return cell
}
}

class CollectionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

enum Constants {
    static let nibName = "CollectionViewCell"
    static let reuseIdentifier = "CollectionViewCell"
}

@IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
private var models: [NewMatch] = []


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    let collectionViewCell = UINib(nibName: Constants.nibName, bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(collectionViewCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Constants.reuseIdentifier)
}

func update(newModels: [NewMatch]) {
    models.removeAll()
    models.append(contentsOf: newModels)
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
}

extension CollectionTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Constants.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else {
        fatalError()
    }

    let model = models[indexPath.section]
    cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: model.imageName)
    cell.userName.text = model.name
    return cell
}
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!

override func prepareForReuse() {
    userImage.image = nil
}
}
```

Comment: :oi did you wrote all of those for just 10 minutes? :OOOOOOOOOOO thank you so much  . it will be so helpful for my studies!

Comment: If your query is solved can you please accept the answer?